# How to display a thumbnail in the hero unit with Bootstrap?

Tags: alignment, thumbnails, twitter-bootstrap

On [this page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html) of the Bootstrap documentation, an example is provided demonstrating the "hero unit" which typically is placed at the top of a page and announces something important. I am trying to incorporate this into a page but I would like to also display a thumbnail beside it. Here is what I have:

```html
<div class="hero-unit">
  <div class="thumbnail span3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="Sample Image">
  </div>
  <h1>Important Site Information</h1>
  <p>This paragraph contains important ... </p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

This *almost* works but there is no gap between the thumbnail and the text:

[image]

Also, the image is overflowing the `hero-unit` div. I realize I can fix both issues with some inline styling:

```html
<div class="hero-unit" style="overflow: auto;">
...
<div class="thumbnail span3" style="margin-right: 20px;">
```

**However,** inline styling really isn't ideal and I am hesitant to apply it site-wide by editing `bootstrap.css`. Is there a better way? I'm sure someone has run into this before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can nest grid elements. So just add another `<div class="row-fluid">` (or `<div class="row">`) inside the hero unit, and then add two `<div class="span...">` blocks with the appropriate percent of the overall grid column units.

Put the image in the left column, and the text in the right.

Comment: I've got [this HTML](http://paste.ubuntu.com/852178/) based on your answer but it it is displaying the thumbnail and text on separate lines.

Comment: That snippet is not based on my answer. Where's your row div?

Comment: Does the row div go inside the `hero-unit` or the `container-fluid` div? Neither seems to work. **Edit:** wait a minute... I think I see what I did wrong...

Comment: I totally messed up there, copying the wrong class name - sorry. Your answer is totally correct and everything works fine now. Thank you.