# How to display two columns in a hero unit with Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alignment, rows

I am trying to get bootstrap's rows to work inside of a hero-unit.  I tired following this example [How to display a thumbnail in the hero unit with Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388597/how-to-display-a-thumbnail-in-the-hero-unit-with-bootstrap) but it doesn't appear to work. I only get 1 column in the hero.  My guess is that the padding is causing the columns to wrap because it appears to align correctly when setting padding to 0, but I'm not sure how to work around that correctly.

```
<div class="hero-unit" style="padding: 15px;">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h2>
            Example Page Header
            <small>Example Sub Header</small>
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/360x268" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="span8">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a sample image even with paint that how do you like your page should be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alex,

If you're using the bootstrap-responsive.css, or the fluid template, then you apply the following markup.

```
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="columnA pull-left">
             <h2>Column A</h2>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300.png"/>
        </div>

        <div class="columnB pull-right">
             <h2>Column B</h2>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300.png"/>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Then insert the following style in the head.

```
  .columnA,
  .columnB{
    width: 500px;

  }
```

The codes above shall output a document similar to the image below:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why spans aren't being used? I thought spans are usually the way to break up information into columns.

Comment: Not sure. I got a similar situation for work just by using `row-fluid`, nothing more.

Answer (score 11):

You can use spans that add up to 11 (instead of 12). No extra css is necessary:

```
<div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span8"> column A </div>
        <div class="span3"> column B </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I used row-fluid, this worked beter than the accepted answer by Gary. In the accepted answer, Gary had you defined widths in the CSS- these have no effect. pull-left and pull-right effectively divide the  hero in two. Use amirnissim's answer above if you need the columns to be diff widths.